# How to draw a vertical line for separating specific section and content?

Tags: macros, line-spacing

While editing my resume, I wanted to place vertical line to separate the *section* part with the content for the section.

Photo attached for clarification.
[image: I need a line divider between Section headings and Content.]

Like this, edited in a sketch app. (watermark, because of unlicensed software)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `minipage` to generate a separation as reqested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.20\textwidth}   %left column
Tech
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill\vline\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}{0.70\textwidth} %right column
lot more text

multi line

wonderful
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Best,
Frank

Answer (score 2):

There may be some other standard solutions but a quick hack is to use the rule command. Give this a try and it might work albeit it isn't the most elegant solution available. Play around with the width and height parameters.

`\rule[depth]{width}{height}`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `res` class. Use `mdframed`. Enter this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    linewidth=1pt,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{separator}
```

then use like this:

```
\section*{Education}
\begin{separator}
PhD in Typesetting, LaTeX University, 2016.
\end{separator}
```

**EDIT: MWE**

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt,line]{res}
\setlength\parskip{5pt}
\usepackage[]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        rightline=false,
        linewidth=2pt,
        innerleftmargin=5pt,
        leftmargin=0pt,
        rightmargin=0pt,
        innerbottommargin=0pt
]{separator}

\begin{document}

\name{Dude Lebowski}

\begin{resume}

\section{Education}
\begin{separator}
PhD in Typesetting, LaTeX University, 2016.

MA, Abiding, Greater Los Angeles, 2011.

BA, Bowling, Los Angeles Alleys, 2009.
\end{separator}

\section{Interests}
\begin{separator}
Bowling

Abiding

White Russians

More bowling

Capers and heists

Rugs that tie the room together
\end{separator}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work as expected. Could you update your answer to include a complete, minimal, working example that shows the use case and output?

Comment: Roger that, MWE added. Key is manually setting the paragraph separator. Can be set to other values.

Comment: So the setting of `\parskip` is purely to align the left/right content? When I have 3 or more pieces of information, there is a mis-alignment.

Comment: `\parskip` sets spacing between items within a section. In the updated MWE there is misalignment with more than three items.

Comment: Sorry I meant there is no misalignment. Lousy thumbs.